# Is "before" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

For a beginner who starts learning English, it is quite surprising that in English you use "before" instead of "in front of" in many occasions. However, it happens and I am getting used to it, but not without any further problem. To make a long story short, is the following sentence correct? What are the possible alternative prepositions or phrases to state this sentence?

> Learning a new language opens new windows **before** you, which can change your whole life.

Are these phrases good alternatives to this aim?

- in front of
- against

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> Learning a new language opens new windows **for** you, which can change your whole life.

*new windows* used here means roughly the same as *new opportunities*. It is not a positional or temporal usage, which would be normal for *before*.